# How to replicate Pandas merge with inner join only using For and If

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to replicate Pandas merge join inner using only for's and if's, but I'm having a hard time.

My input will be two lists of dictionaries, and the output should be a list of dictionaries as well.

```
a = [{'building': 3, 'room':5},{'building': 3, 'room':8},{'building': 2, 'room':3}]
b = [{'building': 3, 'block':4}]

joined_ab = [{'building': 3, 'room':5, 'block':4},{'building': 3, 'room':8, 'block':4}]
```

Update to original question:

I was looking for something more generic that could go over the dictionaries in the list and test if there's a matching on the other list. If matching then join dictionary, proceed to next dict until list of dict is finished. In short, the code should both work for the original problem, but work as well for the case below:

```
a = [{'building': 3, 'room':5},{'building': 3, 'room':8},{'building': 2, 'room':3}]
b = [{'building': 3, 'block':4}, {'building': 2, 'block':2}]
```

returning:

```
joined_ab:[{'building': 3, 'room':5,'block':4},{'building': 3, 'room':8,'block':4},{'building': 2, 'room':3,'block':2}]
```

I think I got it, however I am testing several times same dict. Any ideas for jumping to next dict in the list as soon as I find the first match?

nice list comprehension condensed format suggestions? how about using lambda function?

```
joined_ab = []

for i in b:
     for j in a:
         for ii in i.items():
             for jj in j.items():
                 if ii == jj:
                     ab = j.copy()
                     ab.update(i)
                     joined_ab.append(ab)
```

this code returns correct answer:

```
joined_ab = {'building': 3, 'room': 5, 'block': 4},
 {'building': 3, 'room': 8, 'block': 4},
 {'building': 2, 'room': 3, 'block': 2}]
```

Comment: do you wan to implement it without using pandas?

Comment: what happened to `building:2` ? You want to drop it?

Comment: Exactly, not using pandas

Comment: @Joe Ferndz A merge/join inner would only return the lines from which you have a matching `[key]:value` . So, the 3rd dict in  `a` has no matching info in `b`. Therefore it would be like a null line and not return it

Comment: See if my answer works for you. If you want code for <3.9 ver, i will write up one. Only if and for loop used

Comment: @JoeFerndz I've just added to the original question. I got it, but i'm looking for something more generic, without the need to specify for example what I am testing against. eg `if k['building']==3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 3.9, then you can use | option in dictionary to append two dictionaries.

```
a = [{'building': 3, 'room':5},{'building': 3, 'room':8},{'building': 2, 'room':3}]
b = [{'building': 3, 'block':4}]

joined_ab = [k|b[0]  for k in a if k['building']==3]
print (joined_ab)
```

This will result in:

```
[{'building': 3, 'room': 5, 'block': 4}, {'building': 3, 'room': 8, 'block': 4}]
```

If you are using python < 3.9, then you can give:

```
joined_abx = [{**k,**b[0]}  for k in a if k['building']==3]
```

or

```
joined_aby = [dict(k,**b[0])  for k in a if k['building']==3]
```

Output will be same:

```
[{'building': 3, 'room': 5, 'block': 4}, {'building': 3, 'room': 8, 'block': 4}]
```